# Type error - Switch fragments in the Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have problem of type with my code. I don't understand because my "extends" is correctly put.

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (position == 0) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment())
                .commit();
    } else if (position == 1) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new AnnouncesFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

There is problem with `new HomeFragment()` and `new AnnouncesFragment()`.

Prototype of HomeFragment && AnnoncesFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public class AnnouncesFragment extends Fragment {
```

Error on AndroidStudio is:

> replace (int, android.support.v4.app.Fragment)      in
>   **FragmentTransaction** cannot be applied to      (int, com.xxx.xxxx.xx.AnnouncesFragment)

On android doc:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html

How I use function ->

```
replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're using the latest version of `android.app.Fragment` when extending your classes. You want to use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead.

Comment: `public class HomeFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment` it work, I can compile.. But my app is crashing now. I see that. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Not yet. I have to see what's the problem is. I'm busy now.(work to another project) I will comeback to my android dev very soon. (few days)
#Edit: Ok.. Accepted ^^

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your fragments are instances of `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` and not `android.app.Fragment` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all your fragment related components are instances of `android.support.v4.app...` and not of android.app....

Also create the transaction using the correct fragment manager: use `Activity.getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of Activity.getFragmentManager()

So your fragment must look like:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
...
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
}
```

And the code for the FragmentTransaction:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
...
{
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ftx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ...
    ftx.replace(R.id.my_fragment_id, myFragment);
    ...
    ftx.commit();
}
```